# Ошибка pip - Fatal error in launcher

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

После переустановки Python получаю ошибку при вводе команды pip

```
pip
Fatal error in launcher:
```

После последней строки пустота, никакого описания ошибки. Работает только при указании python -->

```
python -m pip
```

Поиск по поисковикам даёт только результат по ошибке Pip - Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"', а в моем случае нет никакого объяснения ошибки, просто строка Fatal error in launcher:

Python установлен единственный, все path присутствуют, а беспрерывно писать python -m, когда у тебя и так единственный python очень мешает

Comment: На уровне системы или в виртуальном окружении?

Comment: На уровне системы. Вроде даже помню, что-то такое было, а как исправить забыл

Comment: Переустанавливать pip пробовали?

Comment: Это как сделать правильно? До этого не пробовал

Comment: Смотря какая у вас операционная система.

Comment: Windows. Не подскажете?

Comment: Хм. А Python какой и как устанавливали?

Comment: Скачал установщик с офф. сайта. Python 3.6.5